# Como localizar os dados do respectivo mês

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Gostaria de saber como faço para pegar somente os dados do respectivo mês em que estamos.

Por exemplo: tenho a data `2017-05-10` e tenho a data `2017-11-05`, como que eu faço para pegar os dados somente de uma data com MySQL. Quero somente os dados da data `2017-11-05`, ai ele me retorna todos os dados que estão nessa data, como posso fazer isso?

O que eu tenho até agora:

```
mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT data, sum(total) FROM pedidos";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que seja isso que procura:

```
mysqli_query($sql,"SELECT data, sum(total) FROM pedidos WHERE date like '%" . date("Y-m") . "%'");
```

Comment: e isso ai só precisa adaptar no meu caso n seria `date` e sim `data` mas e isso ai obg a ajuda

Comment: Imagina @robertaEDG ;)

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

`mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT data, sum(total) FROM pedidos where data >=" . date('Y-m');`

Comment: nao e isso. vamus supor que eu tenha isso pegando sempre o mes atual em que estamos `$mes = date('Y-m')` ele vai me retornar `2017-11` quero q ele pegue esse `2017-11` que e o ano e o mes e verifique se existe alguma data no banco correspondente a isso se existir listar quais sao com seus respectivos dados

Comment: Editei a resposta com o cód que irá te ajudar.